# How to connect spring boot application to aws document db

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-documentdb

I'm not able to connect my spring boot application to aws document db. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.mercedes-benz.xdrs</groupId>
<artifactId>xdrs_data_service_api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.0</version>
<name>xdrs_data_service_api</name>
<description>xdrs data service api</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.10</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.986</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>xdrs-data-service-api</finalName>
</build>
```

DocumentDBConf.java

```
package com.mercedesBenz.xdrs.dataService.config;

import java.io.File;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;


@Configuration
public class DocumentDBConf {


@Value("${documentdb.connectionString}")
private String connectionString;

@Value("${documentdb.pemFile}")
private String pemFile;

@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() throws Exception {
    // Load the .pem certificate file
    File pemCertificate = new File(pemFile);

    // Enable AWS DocumentDB TLS
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pemCertificate.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit"); // The default trust store password
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
    
    // Enable strong cryptography
    // Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");

    ConnectionString connString = new ConnectionString(connectionString);
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToSslSettings(sslSettingsBuilder -> {
                try {
                    sslSettingsBuilder.enabled(true)
                            .context(SSLContext.getDefault()); // Use the default SSLContext
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating SSL context", e);
                }
            })
            .applyConnectionString(connString)
            .build();

    return MongoClients.create(settings);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "test"); // Replace 'your_database_name' with your actual database name
}
```

}

application.properties

```
documentdb.connectionString=mongodb://user:pwd@xdrs-int-docdb- 
cluster-identifier.cluster-c6wywertyiq6.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/test?tls=true
documentdb.pemFile=/xdrs_data_service_api/src/main/resources/global-bundle.pem
#documentdb.pemFile=classpath:docdb.cert
#documentdb.pemFile=classpath:rds-truststore.jks
management.metrics.mongo.command.enabled=false 
management.metrics.mongo.connectionpool.enabled=false
```

XdrsDataServiceApplication.java

```
package com.mercedesBenz.xdrs.dataService;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, 
MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class XdrsDataServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(XdrsDataServiceApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Image of where my pem file is stored
[image]

In local I am getting following error

[image]

When I deploy the same code in AWS ECS Fargate, I see the following logs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

- First, when connecting locally, you can't connect directly - you need to connect through an SSH tunnel instead. See [Connecting to an Amazon DocumentDB Cluster from Outside an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html) for details on how to do this.
- Second, the `.pem` certificate file isn't directly usable as a Java trust store. Instead, it contains the certificates which should be imported *into* a Java trust store (using the `keytool` Java utility), so that your program can then reference that trust store (via the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property) in verifying the identity of the DocumentDB server.

  - Context: The `sun.security.*` packages (referenced in the Fargate logs you posted) verify the DocumentDB server's identity by attempting to build a valid PKIX certification path from the root CA certificates found in the Java trust store to the certificate presented by the particular DocumentDB server you are targeting. If the Java trust store found at `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` is either invalid (e.g., because it's a `.pem` file instead of a valid `.jks` file), or if it doesn't contain the necessary certificates (e.g., because the root CA certificates found in `global-bundle.pem` were never imported using the Java `keytool` utility), PKIX path building fails, meaning the identity of the DocumentDB server cannot be established. See [Connecting with TLS Enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled) for more details (and be sure to select the "Java" tab to see Java-specific instructions.)